# Iodine is extremely slow

Tags: proxy, dns, tunneling

Finally got iodine working for DNS tunneling but the transfer speed is only 2-3KiB/s.

I testing this on multiple networks and iodine is the bottleneck.

I was expecting something closer to 200-300kbps so is the first figure more accurate or has something gone wrong?